# Import sparse matrix from csv file

Tags: python, csv, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a `csv` file with headers like:

Given this `test.csv` file contains `sparse matrix`:

```
"A","B","C","D","E","F","timestamp"
611.88243,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,9089.5601,0,864.07514,0,0,0
0,0,5133.0,0,0,0,0
```

I simply want to load it as a sparse matrix/ndarray with 3 rows and 7 columns.
If, I use `load.txt` then I get the array with 3 rows and 7 columns.

```
numpy.loadtxt(open("test.csv","rb"),delimiter=",",skiprows=1)
```

Now, my file is actually huge with 10,000 columns and 7000 rows. So, it is taking a lot of time to load. Is there any efficient method in `scipy/numpy` to load the matrix as a sparse matrix or array, so that it takes less amount of time in loading by taking advantage of sparse feature?

Comment: I doubt that loading would be any faster unless you use a sparse format for *storing* the matrix in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this bare bones `loadtxt` on your data (replicated to produce a (39,7) array):

```
def my_loadtxt(file):
    # barebones loadtxt
    f = open(file)
    h = f.readline()
    ll = []
    for l in f:
        y = [float(x) for x in l.split(',')]
        ll.append(y)
    x = np.array(ll)
    f.close()
    return x
```

It was only 2x as fast as `np.loadtxt`.

The result from that could be turned into a sparse mattrix, e.g. `sparse.csr_matrix(loadtext(...))`.  But that step isn't going to save any time.

Conceivably the data line `y` in my function could be turned into a sparse matrix, and those then collected into a large sparse matrix.  But one would have to have a good knowledge of the `scipy.sparse` matrix types to do that efficiently.  I'm not optimistic about it saving time.

---

If you are only going to load this file once, or rarely, you just have to use 'loadtxt' or a simplified version, and accept the time cost.  But if you have to load it frequently, then  saving it in a more efficient form might be worth it.

You could try the simple numpy save and load (though in my tests this is slower).

A couple of the formats in `scipy.io` can save `sparse` matrices.  For example the `matlab` compatible format:

```
io.savemat('stack24426239.mat',{'x2':sparse.csr_matrix(x1)})
x2 = io.loadmat('stack24426239.mat')['x2']
```

In my small tests, this `loadmat` is a bit faster than `my_loadtxt`.  I don't know how it will fare on a much larger file.  The '.mat' is also a bit smaller than the '.txt'.